# How to install mono dev libs on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, c#, gtk, mono-framework, monodevelop

I'm trying to compile an old tomboy addin of mine on Arch, but it seems there are no mono-dev-libs.
MonoDevelop failed to compile because it's missing Unix,Gdk and Gtk.

I also can't find the libs in the aur, do I have to install it all by hand?
Is there a howto for this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to compile MonoDevelop yourself, and I know for a fact that the GTK and GDK assemblies are somewhere in `[community]`. I'm not for sure what `unix` assembly you are talking about however.

Have you tried reading what [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mono) had to say? I followed those instructions to setup a development environment for Mono about 2 weeks ago and didn't have any hang ups

Comment: I found the c#/mono libs on my arch, but monodevelop doesn't found them. the other mono installed libs are found. I imported the tomboy source, worked perfect with monodevelop in fedora15/16.